# How to make some text span both columns of a two-column table

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, alignment, text

I have been trying to duplicate a table with equations found on page 7 of [this document](https://www.hse.ru/data/2015/03/07/1094013810/Tables_in_Signals_and_Systems_Magnus_Lundberg.pdf). I have a problem typesetting the last few rows on that page. For instance, I am not quite sure how the header of Parseval's equation can be centered across both columns. The parts I've circled in blue look off in my implementation.

[image: this is the correct way to write it]

---

[image: this is how mine looks].

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be much easier to help you if you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628), that is, a short but compilable code that reproduces your problem. Otherwise, it would be hard for others to know exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: Without seeing the LaTeX code, it's pretty much impossible to diagnose the situation, let alone suggest a cure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you're struggling mostly with how to typeset material that spans both columns of the two-column table. The command that's your friend in this matter is `\multicolumn{2}{...}{...}`, where `2` is the number of columns that should be spanned. See the code below for three instances of `\multicolumn` calls.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\usepackage{amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcommand\angleN{{<}N{>}}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering\large\mdseries\scshape}
\subsectionfont{\large\mdseries\itshape}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}

% add dots after "numbers" in section and subsection headers
% (method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.)
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control  
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space}       % section
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space} % subsection
\makeatother

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\section{Discrete-time Fourier series}
\subsection{Properties of discrete-time Fourier series}

\begin{center}
$\begin{array}{@{} LL @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\textit{Periodic signal}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\textit{Fourier series coefficients}} \\
\midrule
x[n]=\sum_{k=\angleN}a_ke^{jk(2\pi)/N} &
  a_k=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=\angleN}x[n]e^{-jk(2\pi/N)n} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x_{(m)}[n]=\begin{cases}
    x[n/m],  &\text{if $n$ is a multiple of $m$}\\
    \hfill 0,&\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases} &
  \frac{1}{m}a_k,\quad \text{period $mN$} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\addlinespace
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k] \quad
  \mytab{Bounded and periodic\\only if $a_0=0$} &
\frac{1}{1-e^{-jk2\pi/N}} a_k\\

\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{If $x[n]$ is real-valued then}} \\
\addlinespace

x[n] & 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&a_k = a^*_{-k} \\
&\Re\{a_k\}=\Re\{a_{-k}\} \\
&\Im\{a_k\}=-\Im\{a_{-k}\} \\
&\abs{a_k} = \abs{a_{-k}} \\
&\arg\{a_k\} = -\arg\{a_{-k}\} 
\end{aligned}
\right.
\\
\addlinespace
x_e[n] = \mathcal{E}\{x[n]\} &
  \Re\{a_k\} \\
x_o[n] = \mathcal{O}\{x[n]\} &
  j\Im\{a_k\} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textit{Parseval's relation for periodic signals}} \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{C}{%
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=\angleN} \abs{x[n]}^2 = \sum_{k=\angleN}\abs{a_k}^2} \\

\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```